# View total posts by fans and owners of a Facebook page

Tags: facebook, statistics, facebook-pages

I work for a local news station who is trying to streamline their Facebook page. They tasked me with finding out how to view the tallied data of how many posts are made both by us and by people posting on our wall.

I've checked the Insights section of my Facebook page and I can't seem to find a "total" number of all posts and activity.

Is there any way to find this data and if so how?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this via a user interface in Facebook. You may have to look into the Facebook API and program a solution to tally everything.